# nvm can't install node

Tags: nodejs

I am trying to install a stable version of node, which is now at 16.x. Ubuntu's repositories are at 10.19. I tried to use `nvm` and had these results:

```
@nspiron-N5010:~$ nvm install 16.10.0
Downloading and installing node v16.10.0...
Downloading https://nodejs.org/dist/v16.10.0/node-v16.10.0-linux-x64.tar.xz...
Warning: Failed to create the file
Warning: /home/***/.nvm/.cache/bin/node-v16.10.0-linux-x64/node-v16.10.0-linux-
Warning: x64.tar.xz: Permission denied

0.0%curl: (23) Failure writing output to destination

Binary download from https://nodejs.org/dist/v16.10.0/node-v16.10.0-linux-x64.tar.xz failed, trying source.
grep: /home/***/.nvm/.cache/bin/node-v16.10.0-linux-x64/node-v16.10.0-linux-x64.tar.xz: No such file or directory
Provided file to checksum does not exist.
Binary download failed, trying source.
Detected that you have 4 CPU core(s)
Running with 3 threads to speed up the build
Downloading https://nodejs.org/dist/v16.10.0/node-v16.10.0.tar.xz...
Warning: Failed to create the file
Warning: /home/***/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v16.10.0/node-v16.10.0.tar.xz:
Warning: Permission denied

0.0%curl: (23) Failure writing output to destination

Binary download from https://nodejs.org/dist/v16.10.0/node-v16.10.0.tar.xz failed, trying source.
grep: /home/***/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v16.10.0/node-v16.10.0.tar.xz: No such file or directory
Provided file to checksum does not exist.
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The message is saying you don't have permission to write to the `/home/***/.nvm/.cache/` directory. Is `***` your directory? If so, have you checked the permissions are still set for _you_ and not another account? 

Comment: The "Simple Solution" functioned for node 21.6.2 (The ubuntu latest was v12.22.9).

Answer (score 4):

I tried all suggestions here, but that didn't do it. I tried rebooting, and even downloading that file and placing it in nvm cache bin.. no luch until..

## Simple Solution:

if you have installed `curl` through using `snap` then uninstall that first:

```
sudo snap remove curl
```

then, re-install by using `apt` instead with:

```
sudo apt install curl
```

and now you should be fine to install node with:

```
npm install 18
```

(v18 at the moment, replace `18` with the version you need)

Answer (score 0):

just in case anyone is wonder:  nodejs was updated but needed to ***reboot ubuntu*** instead off and on the terminal as tutorial asked.
Unrebooted system keep showing old version of node when new was already installed and another go with install process messed up with the ubuntu.
So my advice is just to reboot ubuntu not only switch off and on terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, reboot didn't help.

Easy working solution:

1. Follow the link in the terminal and download the file `https://nodejs.org/dist/v20.3.1/node-v20.3.1-linux-x64.tar.xz`
2. Create the path manually and place the downloaded file there `/home/viksua/.nvm/.cache/bin/node-v20.3.1-linux-x64/node-v20.3.1-linux-x64.tar.xz`
3. Reran the command - `nvm install node`

   [image: my Terminal]